# How to assign the value of a variable to a mux outside of a process?

Tags: vhdl

I have a process that implements a state machine. In one of the cycles (states) two signals need to be calculated, where one of them is a calculated directly and the other is a calculation made using the already calculated signal inside a component. The result of the first calculation needs to be put into a MUX that directs into the component, and it all need to be done in the same cycle (which is long enough for both operations to be done serially).

A method that I tried was using a variable to calculate the first signal and then using that signal to calculate the second signal, but it doesn't happen in the same cycle, but in 2 cycles, as the assignment to the first signal happens only at the end of the cycle and the component doesn't have enough time to calculate:

```
when st_cycle_5 =>                   

  vec_var(31 downto 0)  := dot_c_sig(31 downto 0)  - dot_a_sig(31 downto 0);
  vec_var(63 downto 32) := dot_c_sig(63 downto 32) - dot_a_sig(63 downto 32);
  vec_var(95 downto 64) := dot_c_sig(95 downto 64) - dot_a_sig(95 downto 64);

  c_minus_a_sig         <= vec_var;

...

end process cau_proc;

mult1_in1_sig           <= b_minus_a_sig(63 downto 32) when cau_state = st_cycle_5
```

How can I calculate the signal `b_minus_a_sig` and assign it through a MUX to get the result for a component at the same cycle?

(`vec_var` is a variable and all the other signals are `std_logic_vector`)

**EDIT**: There is the solution of putting

```
mult1_in1_sig <= dot_c_sig(63 downto 32) - dot_a_sig(63 downto 32) when cau_state = st_cycle_5
```

But I think that in this case the place & route will not know that that operation was done already and that the result is available and do it twice instead of using the known result.

Comment: Please try to make a completely working, but simple code fragment. Make the names a simple as possible and leave out everything that has nothing to do with your question. http://www.sigasi.com/content/vetsmod-get-better-feedback-your-vhdl-code-snippets

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you simply need to assign `mult1_in1_sig` *inside* your process, using the proper variable or variable's slice.

In other words, you can pack your calculation and your mux in a single process.

Doing so, be careful *not* to describe a *latch*, ie your target signal `mult1_in1_sig` *must* be assigned a value for every possible execution path in your process, not only `when st_cycle_5`. The same remark holds for `c_minus_a_sig` and every signal.